# Site works fine on other browsers except for Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I am new to this coding stuff and I've made a portfolio site and it works fine on chrome and safari but for some reason in Firefox the projects section doesnt work right, theres no skew and I can't click on the more info button, any ideas?
[portfolio site](http://www.franzwiebe.com)

Comment: remove `z-index: -1;` property from `.projects` class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove `z-index: -1;` property from `.projects` class. With `z-index: -1;` you are hiding block with `more info` buttons below the `body` block, and you can't click it.